# Annotation-oriented HTML WYSIWYG editor

Tags: html-editor

I'm looking for a visual HTML editor which is **dedicated** to **annotating** on locally saved static web pages for non-web designers. These pages are clipped with Zotero and Scrapbook for PKM purpose.

More accurately，I want it to be as convenient as annotating on a PDF document in Foxit Reader for example; just select a comment tool via self-customized shortcuts and then make selections on the text manually or by a double-click (to select a single word). Or you can make a selection first and then invoke the comment tool via hotkeys. In other words, it must be very quick to make both a selection and an annotation then.

Colored text-highlighting is a required type of annotation with hotkeys. it is preferred to have one key for each color.

A Firefox extention is preferred while a standalone application is OK.